# How can pass multi query to Master Details c#

Tags: datagrid, devexpress, entity, master-detail, multi-query

I have a Master Details data grid, I want to bind my data entity to the master detail's child.
I don't know how to bind an entity to a child?
Can you help me with that?

```cs
using (IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection("Data Source =.; Initial Catalog = tejarat_iran; Integrated Security = True"))
{
    var multiReport = db.QueryMultiple("SearchReport", new { search = IdCompany, kind = 0 }, null, null, CommandType.StoredProcedure);
    var company = multiReport.Read<Class_entity.companyentity>().AsList();
    var person = multiReport.Read<Class_entity.personEntity>().AsList();
    var product = multiReport.Read<Class_entity.productentity>().AsList();
    tblsherkatBindingSource.DataSource = company;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To use Master-Detail grid,The first thing is read official tutorial.

So, for the [Working with Master-Detail Relationships in Code](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/732/controls-and-libraries/data-grid/master-detail/working-with-master-detail-relationships-in-code#load-details-dynamically-by-handling-events) ,you can know how to [Load Details Dynamically by Handling Events](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/732/controls-and-libraries/data-grid/master-detail/working-with-master-detail-relationships-in-code#load-details-dynamically-by-handling-events)

There are some useful demos in [Examples: Master-Detail Mode](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/3078/controls-and-libraries/data-grid/examples/master-detail/examples-master-detail-mode)